# VueJS how to call API every x seconds (chat)

Tags: vue.js, lumen

just learning Vue and I wanted to build a chat for fun. The only thing I cannot get my head around is how should I watch for "replies" non-stop e.g. you are chatting with someone, but every-time he types a message and presses enter, the message should appear on your screen.

This means that I have to make an API call every 5 seconds or so, to check for new messages right? how would one doe this? in what lifecycle hook and how exactly?

I hope someone can explain a bit to me on how I could do this in the best way.

P.S. I am using VueJS with Lumen (Laravel).

Comment: It's time for you to finally get familiarize with WebSockets! Go for it son.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to poll the server if you're using websockets. The messages will just get sent down as the events arrive. I'd recommend a plugin like Vue-Socket.io: https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io 
Here's a blog article that explains how to build a chat app with the plugin: https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/chatengine/vuejs/chat-app/

The basic solution looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="chat-container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>{{ title + uuid }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <friend-list></friend-list>
      <div class="right-body">
        <div class="table">
          <chat-log></chat-log>
          <message-input></message-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
  import FriendList from '@/components/FriendList';
  import ChatLog from '@/components/ChatLog';
  import MessageInput from '@/components/MessageInput';
  export default {
    name: 'chat-container',
    components: {
      FriendList,
      ChatLog,
      MessageInput,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'PubNub ChatEngine and Vue - User: ',
      };
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        uuid: 'getMyUuid',
      }),
    },
  };
<script>
```

Comment: oh man, that is just awesome! I would need some kind of API storage though cause I want to save the conversations but this is wonderful, thank you so much for your reply!